# No Async method working

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, kinvey

My complete Kinvey and Xamarin Async-API is not working with await/async methods. I dont know where the problem is. I didn't find any error in my code, but the general methods I use should be ok, like

```
User _User= await KinveyXamarin._Client.User().LoginAsync();
```

I searched on the Internet, but I didn't find any similar problems. It returns the Compile_time Error

> Error CS4033: The 'await'  operator can only be used within an async
>   method. Consider marking this method  with the 'async' modifier and
>   changing its return type to 'Task'.

I really dont know whats causing this problem, these are nearly my first steps with asynchronous API and Kinvey. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the error says the method in which you use async methods must also be marked as async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in which you write `await` should be an `async` method itself.

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    User _User = await KinveyXamarin._Client.User().LoginAsync();
    // more code
}
```

If you want to return an object, use `Task<T>`:

```
public async Task<User> MyMethodAsync()
{
    User _User = await KinveyXamarin._Client.User().LoginAsync();
    // more code

    return _User;
}
```

Extra note: please try to [avoid async void](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), it's evil.

Edit: it's a best practice to end your async methods on -Async to make this clear to anyone using your code.